# custom function in R to replace outliers by quartile method

Tags: r, function, dplyr, apply

I have created a function in R to detect and replace outliers by quartile method in R. Function is working but extremely slow for large dataset. Currently my dataset is with 1,000,000 rows and 250 columns. All are numeric.

```
replaceOutliers3 <- function(x, strength,replaceWithNA,na.rm = TRUE, ...)
{
  totalCols<-ncol(x)
  totalRows<- nrow(x)

  for (col in 1:totalCols)
  {
    cat("starting col ...",col)
    cat("\n")
    quantiles <- quantile( x[,col], probs=c(.25, .75 ), na.rm= na.rm, ...)
    if(strength ==1 )
    {
      h<-1.5 * IQR(x[,col], na.rm = na.rm)
    }
    else if(strength ==2)
    {
      h<-3 * IQR(x[,col], na.rm = na.rm)
    }
    else
    {
      stop("Please provide correct strength : 1 for mild , 2 for strong")
    }

    lowerThresh<-quantiles[1] - h
    upperThresh<-quantiles[2] + h

    if(replaceWithNA)
    {
      for (row in 1:totalRows)
      {
        if(x[row, col] < lowerThresh)
        {
          x[row, col] <- NA
        }
        if(x[row, col] > upperThresh)
        {
          x[row, col] <- NA
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for (row in 1:totalRows)
      {
        cat("starting row ...",row)
        cat("\n")
        if(x[row, col] < lowerThresh)
        {
          x[row, col] <- lowerThresh
        }
        if(x[row, col] > upperThresh)
        {
          x[row, col] <- upperThresh
        }
      }
    }
    cat("Column completed :",col)
  }
  return(x)
}
```

I know code is really crude. Can any one please help me code a faster version with **apply** , **dplyr** etc

Comment: This extremely dubious from the statistics perspective.

Comment: Thanks Roland for pointing out. But i had the option to (1) remove the outlier (2) imputation by knn (3) winsorize by threshold values . I also have computation time constraints. Could you suggest me an alternative ?

Comment: top hit from googling `winsorizing in R` http://www.r-bloggers.com/winsorization/

Comment: is the above outlier detection by quartile method not acceptable ? Replacing method might be a bad idea.